# how to solve the error of Could not find a package gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i try to build new package for working with ros and gazebo with

> catkin_create_pkg spcbot_description tf rviz gazebo xacro urdf rospy roscpp std_msgs geometry_msgs

but after i run catkin_make i get

```
 +++ processing catkin package: 'spcbot_description'
 -- ==> add_subdirectory(spcbot/spcbot_description)
 CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo" with any
   of the following names:
 
     gazeboConfig.cmake
     gazebo-config.cmake
 
   Add the installation prefix of "gazebo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
   "gazebo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gazebo"
   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
   installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   spcbot/spcbot_description/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
 
 
 -- Could not find the required component 'gazebo'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the                package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
 CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo" with any
   of the following names:

     gazeboConfig.cmake
     gazebo-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "gazebo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
   "gazebo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gazebo"
   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
   installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   spcbot/spcbot_description/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/home/zora/tuto_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
 See also "/home/zora/tuto_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
 Makefile:556: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
 make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
 Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

there are any solution ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335833/how--to-solve-the-error-of-could-not-find-a-package-gazebo/) by [zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/47277/zahra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need gazebo installed.

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-gazebo*
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/47277/zahra/) on 2019-10-21**:
i installed i have gazebo7

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-10-21**:
either you didnt install it where it can be found or you have an incomplete environment to find it. The error is pretty clear.

**Comment by [zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/47277/zahra/) on 2019-10-21**:
sir i was used

```
curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
```

to install gazebo should i following the Alternative installation ??

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-10-21**:
Try to use the instructions above

**Comment by [zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/47277/zahra/) on 2019-10-21**:
do you mean this

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-gazebo*
```